# $K_\lambda\cong K_\mu\Leftrightarrow\lambda=\mu$ with $K_\lambda :=K[X]/(X-\lambda)$

Tags: linear-algebra

For a field $K$ we define ($\lambda\in K$) $$K_\lambda :=K[X]/(X-\lambda).$$

I have shown so far that $K_\lambda$ has $K$-dimension $1$, a basis is $[1]_\lambda:=[1]$.

Now I claim $$K_\lambda\cong K_\mu\Leftrightarrow\lambda=\mu.$$

One direction is trivial. For the other one: We have an isomorphism $\varphi:K_\lambda\rightarrow K_\mu$. If I can assume $\varphi([X-\mu]_\lambda)=[X-\mu]_\mu$, I can fill in the rest.

But how can I show $\varphi([X-\mu]_\lambda)=[X-\mu]_\mu$?

Comment: Maybe you want $\lambda \neq 0$.

Comment: Can I assume $\varphi([1])=[1]$? $\varphi$ sends a basis onto a basis. But it must not be $[1]_\mu$?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. $K_\lambda \cong K$ for all $\lambda$, so $K_\lambda\cong K_\mu$ regardless of whether $\lambda =\mu$ or not.

Comment: Why should we have $K_\lambda\cong K$?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2096253/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in fact not true. If $K_\lambda$ has dimension $1$, it is isomorphic to $K$ (as a $K$-vector space), and so is $K_\mu$.

We can even show that they are isomorphic as $K$-algebras. Define a map $ev_\lambda : K[X]\to K:p\mapsto p(\lambda)$. It's easy to show that it is a surjective homomorphism of rings, and it follows that $\frac{K[X]}{\ker (ev_\lambda)}\cong K$. Since $\ker(ev_\lambda)=(X-\lambda)$, you get that $K_\lambda\cong K$.