# Quotient Modules of a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R = K[x], K$ a field. Define for $a \space \epsilon \space K$ the ideal $ I_a := (x-a)$ in $K[x]$ and see $I_a$ as an $R$ module. Using that for $ a \space \epsilon \space K$ and  $ b \space \epsilon \space K$, $I_a$ and $I_b$ are isomorphic, prove that the quotient modules $R/I_a$ and $R/I_b$ are not isomorphic as $R$ -modules.

How should I prove this? I have tried doing it with the first isomorphism theorem for modules, constructing a function $ \theta $  with $ ker(\theta) = I_a$ but I don't seem to get anywhere. Does anyone know a proper solution to this question? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the morphism $K[x]\to K$ with $f\mapsto f(a)$?

Comment: Yes I've tried it, the $ker$ is indeed $I_a$ but does this have $R/I_b$ as image? I mean, what seems logic in my eyes is doing a map to $R/I_b$ to show that it is isomorphic to $R/ker(\theta)$ with $ker(\theta)$ being $I_a$ but I don't seem to find a map with $R/I_a$ as image.

Comment: I don't think that this map helps you since it makes $R/I_b$ and $R/I_a$ isomorphic to $K$ via the isomorphism theorems. But this is only as $K$ modules.

Comment: Okay, then how should I do it? I'm really confused now, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to confuse you. I was just trying to elaborate on the point you made in the second paragraph about $ker(\theta)=I_a$. I'm not sure about it either.

Comment: What if I suppose they are isomorphic and construct an isomorphism, would I come to a contradiction? Maybe I could try to to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a isomorphism $f:R/I_b \to R/I_a$ as $R$ modules. Observe that $x=b$ in $R/I_b$ and $x=a$ in $R/I_a$. Then you have

$$ bf(1)=f(b)=f(x)=xf(1)=af(1) $$

Now recall that the module structure in $R/I_a$ comes from the projection map $\pi$. Now by assumption $a\neq b$. And this means $(a-b)f(1)=0$ implies that $f(1)\in I_a$ since $a-b \notin (x-a)=ker(\pi)$ but this means $f(1)=0 $ in $R/I_a$ i.e. $f(1)\in ker(f)$ contradicting $f$ being an isomorphism.

Comment: Ok , I understand most of this. Only, why is $x = b$ in $R/I_b$ and the same for $a$.

Comment: This is true since $R/I_a=K[x]/(x-a)$ and  therefore the equivalence class of $x$ is just $a$ since $x-a=0$ in  $R/I_a$. Same goes for $R/I_b$.

Comment: YES! I get it now, thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

If they were isomorphic, they would have the same annihilator. Unfortunately
$$\operatorname{Ann}_R R/I_a=I_a, \enspace\text{whereas}\quad\operatorname{Ann}_R R/I_b=I_b.$$
Note, however, they're isomorphic as $k$-vector spaces.

Comment: Wow! This is a pretty simple way to look at it, thanks!

Comment: Why are the annihilators _equal_ and not only isomorphic?

Comment: @Alphonse You basically do the same as in my answer to see this. When there is a isomorphism you can use it to see that everything that kills one module also kills the other one.

Comment: @Alphonse: it's more general than this precise situation: if $f\colon M\simeq N$, and if $aM=0$, then for any $n\in N$, we have $n=f(f^{-1}(n))$, so $an=f(af^{-1}(n))=f(0)=0$.